# Extracting and sorting data from a column with the SELECT command

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with codes for multilingual commands with a structure like this:

| id | code | lang | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | exit_command | de | Fenster Schliessen |
| 2 | exit_command | en | Close window |

....
(The column `lang` also contains other languages such as Italian, Japanese, etc.)

I want to extract all texts for German and English from that table sorting them by code.
Running the command below, I get a mix of German and English in the same column:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE (lang='de' or lang='en')`

But I would like to have a column for lang=English with English Text in a separate column and a column for lang=German with German Text in a separate column.

The structure of the output should look like this:

| code | lang | German text | lang | English text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| exit_command | de | Fenster schliessen | en | Close window |

...

How can I get this output with an SQL query? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you share an example of the output you want from this data, just so the question is a bit clearer?

Comment: Hi @Mureinik, I added an example of the output I would like to have.

Answer (score 2):

I'd join two subqueries on the table by their `code`:

```sql
SELECT de.code, de.lang, de.text, en.lang, en.text
FROM   (SELECT code, lang, text
        FROM   mytable
        WHERE  lang = 'de') de
JOIN   (SELECT code, lang, text
        FROM   mytable
        WHERE  lang = 'en') en ON de.code = en.code
```

Comment: Thank you @Mureinik,
Running your query gives me the following error message:
```Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect Syntax near en.```

Comment: @N_user oops... forgot the join clause..

Answer (score 2):

This problem falls into the pivot task:

- The `CASE` expression will help you extract the values you need.
- The `MAX` aggregation will allow you to remove the unneeded NULL values, with respect to the partition (`GROUP BY code_`).

```
SELECT code_,
       'de' AS lang1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN lang = 'de' THEN text_ END) AS GermanText,
       'en' AS lang2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN lang = 'en' THEN text_ END) AS EnglishText
FROM tab
GROUP BY code_
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qwwvVhYFKu5VGTWR6YVjnZ/0).